Replacing Tile Server
I have an existing GUI desktop application that consumes tiles in a {Z}/{X}/{Y}.png format from a cloud server using this guide https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-18-04-osm, but want to improve the performance as generating new tiles takes far too long(about 1minute for a new set of tiles). The server is a 16core VPS with 64GB RAM and a 5TB NVME SSD.
I setup a https://github.com/protomaps/go-pmtiles server which creates .mvt tiles very quickly, but lack the ability to convert that to a PNG which can then be served. I did see the pmtiles server can serve .png files in their documentation, but have been unable to format the .pmtile data in a way that allows that to work. I tried converting the .mvt tile to a PNG with various tools but had no success. It looked for a period I could get libmapnik to render a tile to PNG either on the server or client side, but the lack of examples and documentation online made that too difficult and I gave up.
I am looking for any solution that will allow me to make relatively few changes to the desktop rendering side as it would be an enormous job to change that. So that it essentially still consumes 256x256 images as tiles. I would like up to zoom level 19 or more if possible, but understand this may not fit within the the available space I can suffice with less.

Can you clarify "about 1minute for a new set of tiles"?  About 1 minute for 1 high-zoom time would be a long time; 1 minute for "all the tiles in the world" would be very fast indeed!

So if I setup a server, and request 3/2/1.png, it will take about a minute for it to generate that tile and present it.
